# getting all mounting directories with a specific name

Tags: path, pipe, concatenation, ls

I am trying to receive all mounting directories with a specific name in order to pipe them into another command.

within `/mnt/` there are 2 folders, `plotfield1` and `plotfield2`
`ls|grep plotfield` properly returns those two foldernames:
[image]

but what I am looking for is the full path:

```
/mnt/plotfield1
/mnt/plotfield2
```

Currently, for testing, I use this:

```
cd /mnt/
test=$(ls|grep plotfield|cat <(echo -n '/mnt/') -)
echo $test
```

the result is unexpected, only the first string is concatenated:
[image]

is there a better way to get the full path of the files?
the goal would be something like this pseudocode:
`ls|grep plotfield|concat|xargs chia plots add -d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be straightforward using a glob expression like `plotfield*` and using the builtin `printf` to put the output to standard output, i.e. from any path

```sh
printf '%s\n' /mnt/plotfield*
# or 
printf '%s\n' /mnt/plotfield?
```

Also for storing multiple lines of output, use an array type to hold your values. So to store the above lines to an array, use `mapfile` or `readarray`

```sh
mapfile -t paths < <(printf '%s\n' /mnt/plotfield?)
```

and pass the array expansion `"${paths[@]}"` to any other commands as needed.